# How to fix Rails 5.2 console that won't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

Rails console won't start in development. Rails server does start but not console. Running Ruby 2.5.1, Rails 5.2.2.1

Tried a number of similar looking errors on this site for the server not starting but could not find similar error for console. Tried commenting out both spring gems. No change. Tried commenting out bootsnap gem and that didn't work either.

error

```
rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 772
Traceback (most recent call last):
    50: from -e:1:in `<main>'
    49: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    48: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    47: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
    46: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    45: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
    44: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
    43: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
    42: from /Users/me/Documents/projects/hosting/principle/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    41: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    40: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    39: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    38: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    37: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    36: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    35: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    34: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    33: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    32: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    31: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:70:in `find_by_namespace'
    30: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:79:in `lookup'
    29: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:79:in `each'
    28: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:80:in `block in lookup'
    27: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:80:in `each'
    26: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:84:in `block (2 levels) in lookup'
    25: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    24: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    23: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    22: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    21: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    20: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    19: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    18: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    17: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:4:in `<main>'
    16: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    15: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    14: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    13: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    12: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    11: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    10: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     9: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
     8: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `<main>'
     7: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     6: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     5: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     4: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
     3: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     2: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     1: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': dlopen(/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/readline.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/readline.bundle
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'


gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2', '>= 5.2.2.1'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'administrate', github: 'excid3/administrate', branch: 'zeitwerk'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.6', '>= 4.6.1'
gem 'devise-bootstrapped', github: 'excid3/devise-bootstrapped', branch: 'bootstrap4'
gem 'devise_masquerade', '~> 0.6.2'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.6', '>= 5.6.1'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.2', '>= 5.2.5'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', github: 'mdeering/gravatar_image_tag'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.9', '>= 4.9.2'
gem 'name_of_person', '~> 1.1'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 5.0'
gem 'omniauth-github', '~> 1.3'
gem 'omniauth-twitter', '~> 1.4'
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 5.2', '>= 5.2.5'
gem 'sitemap_generator', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
gem 'whenever', require: false
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0.1'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try reinstalling ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
```

tells you that Ruby doesn't find that version of Readline anymore which it was built against:

The reason might be that you ran `brew upgrade` recently and updated readline to version 8 on your machine, but Ruby is still expecting version 7.

You have two options:

1. De-install Ruby on your machine and re-install it. This would build Ruby against your latest readline version. Or
2. Add a symlink that allows Ruby to find your current version of readline when it is looking for the old version.

To add that symlink open your terminal and simply run:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for an error at the beginning of the log. I thought that errors are at the beginning of a read out. I also chose the second option and added the symlink.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning bootsnap cache (`rm -rf tmp/cache/bootsnap-*`), if that does not help - reinstall ruby